# Pollard p - 1 implementation

Tags: java, performance, mathematics, integer

I'm trying to implement the Pollard p - 1 algorithm seen [here](http://ardoino.com/2004/03/maths-factoring-pollard/), in Java.
It has a C implementation [here](http://ardoino.com/pub/maths/pollard/pollard.txt). I am using it for numbers without any smaller factors so trial factorisation isn't needed.  My implementation can factor numbers such as `15236506168104630133` but it takes around ten minutes. I also would like it to factor number of up to 30 digits with it. Is there any improvements I can make?

```
public static void factorise(BigInteger number){

    BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(10);
    //b!
    BigInteger k = Utils.factorial(b);        


    while(true){

        //random number a from number 0 to n-2
        BigInteger a = Utils.generateRandomNumber(number).add(BigInteger.valueOf(-1));

        BigInteger tmp = a.modPow(k, number);
        //a^k - 1 (mod n)
        tmp.add(BigInteger.valueOf(-1));
        //gcd(a^k - 1 (mod n), number);
        BigInteger gcd = tmp.gcd(number);

        if(gcd.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0){

            if(gcd.isProbablePrime(100)){
                System.out.println("Factor:d " + gcd);

                number = number.divide(gcd);

            }


            if(number.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0){
               System.out.println("done");
                return;
            }

            if(number.isProbablePrime(10)){
                 System.out.println("Factor: " + number);
                 return;
            }


        }



    }

}





public static BigInteger generateRandomNumber(BigInteger number){

    BigInteger random;
    do {
        random = new BigInteger(number.bitLength(), new SecureRandom());
    } while (random.compareTo(number) >= 0);

    return random;

}

public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger number){

    BigInteger mul = number.add(BigInteger.valueOf(-1));

    while(mul.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(1)) != 0){

        number = number.multiply(mul);
        mul = mul.add(BigInteger.valueOf(-1));

    }        

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really really hate when the comments (which are supposed to help) don't agree with the code. Because now you don't know which is correct (the code or the comments).

```
    //random number a from number 0 to n-2
    BigInteger a = Utils.generateRandomNumber(number).add(BigInteger.valueOf(-1));
```

When writing comments. **DO NOT** put a comment for each obvious line of code. The code describes itself I don't need you to tell me what the line of code does. I can actually read code (as can everybody that will read your code).

When you write comments describe the algorithm that your code is trying to implement (preferably with a link to a static page that will never move (wikipidia) that not only describes the algorithm but what its trying to do (or put it in the comments at the top of a chunk of code). Describe **WHY** you are using the algorithm and what the final result will be.

#### Code:

```
    //random number a from number 0 to n-2
    BigInteger a = Utils.generateRandomNumber(number).add(BigInteger.valueOf(-1));
```

If this actually generates a random number in that range then I would seriously kick the implementer of `generateRandomNumber` for generating an initial range of [1..(number-1))

This comment is even stranger:

```
    BigInteger tmp = a.modPow(k, number);
    //a^k - 1 (mod n)
    tmp.add(BigInteger.valueOf(-1));
```

Really. Not sure what the heck is happening here.

What is it with all the usless white space.

```
            }


        }



    }

}
```

Maybe I should kick the implementor of `generateRandomNumber`

```
public static BigInteger generateRandomNumber(BigInteger number){
```

That is not doing what the name suggests it is doing.

Yep sure the loop is going to work:

```
do {
    random = new BigInteger(number.bitLength(), new SecureRandom());
} while (random.compareTo(number) >= 0);
```

But why have the loop. Why not generate a random one smaller than the max than add one.

Also why are you creating a new random number generator on each iteration `new SecureRandom()`. You just create than once (in the entire life cycle of the program) then use the instance every time.